# jQuery UI Sortable - Remove placeholder after item is dropped

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to do a nested sortable and I'm kind'a succeeding, but there's one small little inconvenience that bugs me.

I want the placeholder to disappear only after I've dropped the currently dragged item (on mouseup) and I can't quite figure out how to do it.

I want to do this because when I sort downwards, the deletion of the placeholder affects the parent's height, which in turn creates a small bug, check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5y8LwL2g/) here.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">     
    <h1>Menu</h1>
    <ul class="list-group striped nest">
        <li class="list-group-item">Home <ul class="list-group striped nest"></ul></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">About <ul class="list-group striped nest"></ul></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            Services
            <ul class="list-group striped nest">
                <li class="list-group-item">Design <ul class="list-group striped nest"></ul></li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Programming<ul class="list-group striped nest"></ul></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Contact <ul class="list-group striped nest"></ul></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>

            Empty nestable

            <ul id="collapseExample" class="collapse list-group striped nest" aria-expanded="false"></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.nest {
    min-height: 42px;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.nest:empty {
    border: 1px dashed #ddd;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

ul.nest li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul.nest:first-child {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.bg-info {
    min-height: 42px;
    list-style: none;
}

.striped li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

**Script**

```
$(function() {

  $('.nest').sortable({
    connectWith: ".nest",
    items: "> li",
    axis: "y",
    cursor: "row-resize",
    opacity: 0.5,
    placeholder: "bg-info"
  }).disableSelection();

});
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more detailed what do you refer with _which in turn creates a small bug_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you drag the *`li.list-group-item(selected tag)`* sortable plugin adding another tag *`li.ui-sortable-placeholder`* to show it as empty placeholder, and this tag moves as you drag the selected tag.

As per you statement:

> I want the placeholder to disappear only after I've dropped the
>   currently dragged item (on mouseup) and I can't quite figure out how
>   to do it.

To do this I added another placeholder in the following code *`$bgPlaceholder`*.
When you move the selected tag it will add *`$bgPlaceholder`* after the selected tag, and removes *`$bgPlaceholder`* when you drop the selected tag.

And also adding and *`.selected-tag`* class to selected tag.

```
$(function() {

var $bgPlaceholder = '<li class="bg-placeholder"></li>';
var draggable = false;
var isInMove = false;
$('.nest').sortable({
    connectWith: ".nest",
    items: "> li",
    axis: "y",
    cursor: "row-resize",
    opacity: 0.5
}).disableSelection();

$(".nest").on("mousedown", "li.list-group-item", function() {
    draggable = true;
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass("selected-tag");
});

$(".nest").on("mousemove", "li.list-group-item", function() {
    if (draggable && !isInMove) {
        isInMove = true;
        var $this = $(this);
        $($bgPlaceholder).insertAfter($this);
    }
});

$(".nest").on("mouseup", "li.list-group-item", function() {
    draggable = false;
    isInMove = false;
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass("selected-tag");
    $(".nest").find(".bg-placeholder").remove();
});

});
```

and CSS

*`li.ui-sortable-placeholder`* will be hidden when its adjacent to *`.selected-tag`* and *`.bg-placeholder`*, this is to hide unnecessary empty placeholder at selected tag.

```
.bg-placeholder {
min-height: 42px;
list-style: none;
background-color: red!important;
}

.bg-placeholder + .ui-sortable-placeholder {
display: none;
}

.selected-tag + .ui-sortable-placeholder {
display: none;
}
```

Example : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5y8LwL2g/2/)

Comment: Good Job Pavan Kumar :)

Comment: Thank You for the detail :)

Comment: Thanks mate, this is it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired output indicated, we need to perform a draggable and sortable functions for the List Items and Header respectively.

```
$('.nest:has(li)').sortable({
   connectWith: ".nest",
   items: "> li",
   axis: "y",
   cursor: "row-resize",
   opacity: 0.5,
   placeholder: "bg-info",
 }).disableSelection();

$('.nest:has(li)>li').draggable({       
    tolerance:"pointer",
    refreshPositions: true ,
    opacity:.4,
});
```

And then we need the property connectToSortable:'.nest' and helper: 'clone' for the draggable function to apply the sort functionality to the draggable function of the listitem and to clone the listitem after dragged. The clone will stay in the item.

```
helper : 'clone',
connectToSortable: '.nest',
```

When the draggable function has applied the sortable content, we need to remove the clone. To do that, add receive functionality in the sortable function

```
receive: function (event, ui) {
    ui.item.remove();
}
```

```js
$(function() {

  $('.nest:has(li)').sortable({
    connectWith: ".nest",
    items: "> li",
    axis: "y",
    cursor: "row-resize",
    opacity: 0.5,
    placeholder: "bg-info",
    receive: function(event, ui) {
      ui.item.remove();
    }
  }).disableSelection();

  $('.nest:has(li)>li').draggable({
    tolerance: "pointer",
    helper: 'clone',
    refreshPositions: true,
    opacity: .4,
    connectToSortable: '.nest',
  });
});
```

```css
ul.nest {
  min-height: 42px;
  margin: 0;
}
ul.nest:empty {
  border: 1px dashed #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
ul.nest li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.nest:first-child {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.bg-info {
  min-height: 42px;
  list-style: none;
}
.striped li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Menu</h1>
  <ul class="list-group striped nest">
    <li class="list-group-item">Home
      <ul class="list-group striped nest"></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">About
      <ul class="list-group striped nest"></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      Services
      <ul class="list-group striped nest">
        <li class="list-group-item">Design
          <ul class="list-group striped nest"></ul>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Programming
          <ul class="list-group striped nest"></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Contact
      <ul class="list-group striped nest"></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>

      Empty nestable

      <ul id="collapseExample" class="collapse list-group striped nest" aria-expanded="false"></ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```